# Como dar refresh na página?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Eu precisava que quando a pessoa clicasse em um botão na página anterior ele passasse para a próxima página e desse um refresh. Como que faço isso?

Preciso desse refresh pois senão vou ter que fazer uma "gambiarra" para poder funcionar um carrinho de compras no botão estou usando um `window.location`.

Comment: De o window.location.href = "destino";, e na pagina de destino de um window.location.reload();

Comment: Se ele passa de uma página para a outra a página já não é recarregada? Então por quê precisa recarregá-la novamente? E mesmo se isso fazer sentido de alguma forma, parece-me que a solução é, de fato, utilizar o `window.location`, então recomendo [edit] a pergunta e adicionar o seu código.

Comment: Ele funciona perfeitamente o carrinho de compras, mas um motivo tosco se a pessoa passar para a outra página ele carrega muitas vezes com as informações corretas, mas em certos casos nem carrega os dados. Já procurei por todo o código e a única solução encontrada é dar um refresh na página

Comment: @RickPariz ele não vai dar reload toda a hora que carregar a página?

Comment: Então coloca o código na pergunta para tentarmos entender o problema real. Ficar atualizando a página até exibir coo pretende me parece bastante gambiarra.

Comment: @FelipeMichaeldaFonseca Vai

Comment: É que ao invés dele ir para a outra página e pegar os valores das DIVS ele simplesmente não pega os valores daquela página, ou seja, ele pega sem nenhum valor, dado como nulas. Dai se eu der um F5 ele já pega pois carregou a página.

Comment: Coloca o código na pergunta, por favor. Enquanto isso votarei para fechar a pergunta, pois nada que está dizendo está fazendo sentido.

Answer (score 3):

Use `onClick` com `window.location.reload()`:

```
 <input type="button" value="Refresh Page" onClick="window.location.reload()">
```

Comment: Vou dar um up, pois o window.location.reaload() me serviu. rs

Answer (score -2):

Você pode criar uma variável e utilizar ela quando quiser

const refreshPage = () => {
window.location.reload();
};

ou usar diretamente no input caso seja somente para um.